# returnStdout doesn't work when jenkins agent is started as a systemd service

Tags: linux, jenkins, systemd

I have created the below unit file to create a systemd service on linux. This file launches jenkins agent on the machine. I have a stage in my pipeline in which the slave machine will be rebooted. Creating a service that starts after reboot was the solution that I was able to come up with, so that my pipeline execution can continue after reboot.

```
[Unit]
Description=Run jenkinsAgent at startup
After=network.target

[Service]
WorkingDirectory=/home/qatest/jenkins
Type=simple
ExecStart=/bin/bash /home/qatest/jenkins/jenkinsAgent.sh
StandardOutput=journal+console

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

My pipeline (*groovy*) uses `hostName = sh(script: "hostname", returnStdout: true)`. But when the jenkins agent is started as a systemd service and the job is run, `hostName` is returned as empty.

If I start the jenkins agent manually in a shell using `sudo ./jenkinsAgent.sh`, then the `sh` works fine for the job run. ( *my user is in the sudoers list* ).

I initially thought that the std out of the systemd service was not directed properly, so I tried `StandardOutput=journal+console` in the unit file, but to no avail.

What am I missing here ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I modified the unit file as shown below and the issue got resolved.

```
[Unit]
Description=Run jenkinsAgent at startup
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=/usr/bin/java -jar /home/qatest/jenkins/agent.jar -jnlpUrl http://.../slave-agent.jnlp -secret ... -workDir "/home/qatest/jenkins"

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```